# How can I keep the text that the user has highlighted, highlighted when then click elsewhere?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the user type into a textarea, and then be able to edit certain parts of what they typed by highlighting what they want to edit, then clicking a button just outside the textarea. (e.g, bold/color change, etc)

I'm using getSelection() to find the part that they have selected, however when they click on the button to change the text, it cancels out the selected text.

Is there a way that I can keep the text highlighted even if they click on one of the buttons?

Thanks!

EDIT: So the two things I'm unsure on are:

1. How to keep the highlighted part highlighted after the user clicks one of the buttons on a different part of the page.
2. I know that right now this code would change the entire textarea, so how would I get it to just affect the selected text?

Javascript

```
var bold = 0
function boldText()
    {
        if (bold == 0)
            {
                var selected1 = getSelection()
                document.getElementById('default').style.fontWeight="bold";
                bold = 1
            }
        else
            {
                var selected1 = getSelection()
                document.getElementById('default').style.fontWeight="normal";
                bold = 0
            }
    }
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="smallCell" onClick="boldText()"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
        <td class="smallCell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <textarea id="default">Type your message here</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: instead of adding css..you can add strong tags around the selected text

Comment: You've taken out the code that uses `getSelection()` which is the function that you described having a problem with.

Comment: oops got confused..I was expecting some div with contentediable true

Comment: If you're just trying to figure this out for knowledge's sake then cool, but this sounds like you're trying to make a WISIWIG editor of sorts in which case you might want to check out something like: http://www.tinymce.com/ instead of rolling your own solution.

Comment: I put the code with getSelection() back in elsewhere, as it better demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

@Ian I'm just doing this to learn and improve my skills, I know there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Cool, well I think first off you need to re-think your approach. As far as I know you can't edit individual sections of text within a text box. Also getSelection() needs to be -> window.getSelection().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, considering your second point, you probably won't be able to use a textarea to achieve what you want: you will have to create DOM nodes inside the text itself, which is not supported by textarea.

However, this should help you with your first question: http://jsfiddle.net/noziar/2hV3X/

HTML:

```
<p><button type="button" onclick="boldText()">Bold!</button></p>
<p><textarea id="default" rows="4" cols="40" onselect="saveSelection()">
Some sample text here. Try selecting part of it and clicking on the button!
</textarea></p>
```

JS:

```
var start, end, bold;
function saveSelection() {
  var element = document.getElementById('default');
  start = element.selectionStart;
  end = element.selectionEnd;
}
function setSelection() {
  var element = document.getElementById('default');
  element.selectionStart = start;
  element.selectionEnd = end;
}
function boldText() {
  var element = document.getElementById('default');
  element.style.fontWeight="bold";
  if (bold == 0){
    element.style.fontWeight="bold";
    bold = 1;
  } else {
    element.style.fontWeight="normal";
    bold = 0;
  }
  setSelection();
}
```